# FileMaker Pro 18 Runtime Apple Developer Certificate

Tags: macos, filemaker

I need to create a certified runtime from my Filemaker application which required an Apple Develeoper Certificate. I purchased the certificate and followed some instructions on how I can sign my application with the certificate.

I created it in the keychain (following the official apple documentation) and it appears to be okay, here's a screenshot:

[image: Apple Keychain]

It's shown as active. Then I followed this [Instruction](https://www.mbs-plugins.com/archive/2014-08-22/Code_Signing_FileMaker_Runtime) and modifed the script, but if I try to access my certificate I always get the error:

> error the specified item could not be found in the keychain

This error occurs in the following line of the script:

```
codesign -f -vvvv -s "Developer ID Installer: Dieter K****** (D********)"
```

I can't find any errors in the syntax of my script, all other steps work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use "Developer ID Application" certificate.
Refer this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBsFCrI_wXA